# UNIX Programming, splitting screen with fork, exec, and communicating with pipe

Tags: c, unix, pipe, exec, fork

I am trying to write a program on UNIX that splits the screen or terminal in half, spawns a new process on the new screen and close it with commands sent from the original. I am programming using the C language and the GCC compiler.
According to my knowledge, this would be possible by running the fork+exec functions to create the separate process, and communication would be done through the pipe function.

Is this possible, and/or has it been done before?
I would very much like to do my work using an existing project.

Comment: You need to use something like curses library to do screen splitting. Forking does not come into it.

Comment: What have you tried? In what language? How did it work or not work? Do you have problem with the process handling, the pipes, splitting the screen, something else?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I apologize for the ambiguity; I am coding using the C language and gcc compiler, and I am having trouble with splitting the screen. I have successfully run a simple program in which a new process with separate code is created by fork and exec, and have successfully exchanged data using the most basic form of the pipe function, should I elaborate more on this part?
I am wondering if it were possible to run the new process on a new screen so that I can see what is going on in both processes, and more particularly without using additional software.

Comment: @EdHeal I am trying to spawn a new process from the current one. Would this not require forking?

Comment: Then I suggest you either learn about e.g. [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), or special programs such as screen or tmux (as suggested by Doug Luce in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

When I've done something similar to what you're describe, I've used [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) to handle the display output (in particular, the `-X` option to have it do things like split windows and start commands).  I imagine [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) has similar control abilities. I've usually used another mechanism (pipes, sockets, or files) to coordinate input/output between processes.